# Euler Characteristic of a Variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, euler-characteristics

Let $Y$ be a "nice" scheme. I am thinking projective varieties over an algebraically closed field, for now, but I am open to more general results.

In terms of singular homology (coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$), one can define the Euler characteristic $\chi(Y)$.

My question is:

> Can I express $\chi(Y)$ in terms of the Euler characteristic of certain coherent sheaves on $Y$, in terms of sheaf cohomology?

Most preferably, I would like $$\chi(Y)=\chi(Y,\mathcal{F})$$ for some particular sheaf $\mathcal{F}$.

I am sorry if this is really trivial or widely known, my searching and asking (in the real world) has led me nowhere so far.

Comment: Jesko -- if you are willing to accept complexes of sheaves rather than just sheaves, then in characteristic 0 one may take the sum over all smooth strata of the Euler characteristics of the complexes of differential forms.

Comment: Something to keep in mind, Euler characteristic of a coherent sheaf cannot vary in a flat family, but topological Euler characteristic of varieties certainly can.

Comment: Well, in a *smooth* flat family the fibres are diffeomorphic by Ehresmann theorem, so the topological Euler number is constant. But if the family is not smooth, it can definitely vary (think of a smooth plane cubic degenerating to a nodal one). 

Comment: Your comments seem like this is not going to be as simple as I sought it to be. @algori: Could you elaborate on this a bit more? And, what are (smooth) strata?

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$ one can use hodge theory to write $H^k(X,\mathbb{C})=\oplus_{p+q=k}H^q(X,\Omega_X^p)$, where $\Omega_X^p$ is the sheaf of $p$-forms on $X$.

Comment: Of course, you would want the choice of $\mathcal{F}$ to be natural
in some sense, and also you would  want $Y$ to be proper so that the euler characteristic is finite.  And following algori comment,
$\F$ may as well be a virtual sheaf (i.e. a formal linear combination).
When your variety is smooth and projective, Daniel's suggestion 
of $\sum \pm \Omega^p_X$ is the  most reasonable. Other choices are possible in general, but I won't go into it, unless I have a clearer
idea of what you need it for.

Comment: Also the top Chern class of the tangent sheaf gives the topological Euler characteristic (of a smooth, projective, complex variety).

Comment: @Jesko: smooth strata means this: write $X = X_0 \cup X_1 \cup \cdots \cup X_n$ where $X_0$ is the non-singular locus of $X$, $X_1$ is the non-singular locus of $X \setminus X_0$, etc.

Comment: Let X be a smooth projective surface over an alg closed field. By Gauss-Bonnet, as mentioned by Jason Starr, "Euler char. of Y" = c_2(Y). By Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch, $c_1^2(Y) + c_2(Y) = 12\chi(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$. Thus, "Euler char. of Y" = $12\chi(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)-c_1^2(Y)$. So, up to the self-intersection of a canonical divisor, the Euler characteristic is the Euler characteristic of the structure sheaf. (By "Euler char of Y" I mean the one defined using etale cohomology with Q_l-coefficients. Over the complex numbers this is the same as the one defined using singular cohomology with Q-coeff)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, these are a couple of very nice results. Many of those comments would have made good answers, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the answer/reference [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/237363/12218) might be exactly what you are looking for.

On the other hand, perhaps you just want to relate natural algebro-geometric structure to the classical Euler characteristic.  Here is one way to do that:

A pure Hodge structure of weight $k$ is a finite dimensional complex vector space $V$ such that $V=\bigoplus_{k=p+q} H^{p,q}$ where $H^{q,p}=\overline{H^{p,q}}$. This gives rise to a descending filtration
$F^{p}=\bigoplus_{s\ge p}H^{s,k-s}$. Define $\mathrm{Gr}^{p}_{F}(V)=F^{p}/ F^{p+1}=H^{p,k-p}$.

A mixed Hodge structure is a finite dimensional complex vector space $V$ with a real ascending  *weight* filtration $\cdots \subset W_{k-1}\subset W_k \subset \cdots \subset V$ and a descending *Hodge* filtration $F$ such that $F$ induces a pure Hodge structure of weight $k$ on each $\mathrm{Gr}^{W}_{k}(V)=W_{k}/W_{k-1}$. Then define $H^{p,q}= \mathrm{Gr}^{p}_{F}\mathrm{Gr}^{W}_{p+q}(V)$ and $h^{p,q}(V) =\dim H^{p,q}$.

Let $Z$ be any quasi-projective algebraic variety. The cohomology groups  with compact support $H^k_c(Z)$ are endowed with mixed Hodge structures by seminal work of Pierre Deligne.

The *Hodge numbers* of $Z$ are $h^{k,p,q}_{c}(Z)= h^{p,q}(H_{c}^k(Z))$, and the $E$-polynomial is defined as 
 $$
 E(Z; u,v)=\sum _{p,q,k} (-1)^{k}h^{k,p,q}_{c}(Z) u^{p}v^{q}.
 $$

From this, one gets the classical Euler characteristic $\chi(Z)=E(Z;1,1)$.

Note:  if the counting function of $Z$ over finite fields is a polynomial in the order of the finite field, then $E(Z)$ is exactly the counting polynomial.  From this point-of-view, in this case, the Euler characteristic is the number of $\mathbb{F}_1$-points.

Comment: Indeed, the latter is what I want(ed)! Thanks for answering this old question.