# Euler characteristic - reference question

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over $\mathbb C$ and let $\mathcal F$ be a constructible sheaf on $X$. It is well-known that the Euler characteristic of the cohomology of $\mathcal F$ is equal to the Euler characteristic of cohomology with compact support. What is the right reference for this result? 
In $l$-adic cohomology this was proved first by Laumon (I think) but over $\mathbb C$ this should have been known before.

Comment: Surely you want some additional hypotheses, after all $\mathcal F=0$ is constructible.

Comment: @Donu $\mathcal F=0$ has vanishing Euler characteristic with or without compact support.

Comment: Never mind, it's too early in the morning here.

Comment: Sullivan, in "Combinatorial invariants of analytic spaces" (1971), comes close to stating this result. To get the result from what Sullivan does, one needs to use that algebraic varieties have a Whitney stratification, and that a tubular neighborhood of a stratum is a fiber bundle whose fiber is a cone over the link. Sullivan's argument shows that the tubular neighborhood has vanishing Euler characteristic, and then the result follows from Mayer-Vietoris. So it does indeed seem plausible that the result over $\mathbb C$ was known to experts before Laumon's result in the $\ell$-adic case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper you refer to by Gérard Laumon appears to be:

*Comparaison de caractéristiques d'Euler-Poincaré en cohomologie l-adique,* 
C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. I Math. 292 (1981), no. 3, 209–212.

According to the MathSciNet Review of this paper (reference MR0610321) by William E. Lang:

> "As a corollary, the author deduces that if $k$ is algebraically closed, and if $X$ is a separated scheme of finite type over $k$, then for all $E_\lambda$-sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, $\chi(X,\mathcal{F})=\chi_c(X,\mathcal{F})$. This corollary had been previously proved by A. Grothendieck for curves in all characteristics [ibid., (SGA 5 X), pp. 372–406], and in all dimensions when the characteristic of $k$ is zero."

According to the reference, that was in 1965–1966.